# How to include code-block in Shiny App helpText()

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have the following **ui.R**

```
library(datasets)

# Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
fluidPage(    

  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Telephones by region"),

  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      

    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("region", "Region:", 
                  choices=colnames(WorldPhones)),
      hr(),
      helpText("Some text and then some code.")
    ),

    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("phonePlot")  
    )

  )
)
```

Where the [helpText()](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/helpText.html) produces:

```
<span class="help-block">
 Some text and then some code.
</span>
```

How can I modify helpText so that in can include code block:

```
<span class="help-block">
 Some text and then <code>some code</code>.
</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
helpText("Some text and then ", code("some code"), ".")
```